# R How to vary color and width of a line to show more information

Tags: r, plot, line

I'd like to change the line width and/or color along the line to indicate a third and fourth quantity.  This seems to work a little.  But, I need help fine tuning the colors and line width.  Something along the lines of color palete based on red/yellow/green and line widths with control of the break.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
nt<-50
t<-seq(nt)
psi<-seq(0,pi,length.out=nt)
a<-2
tmp1 <- data.table( theta = psi )
tmp1[,R := 4 * a * cos(theta) * sin(theta) * sin(theta) ]
tmp1$group = 1
library(pracma)
a<-4
tmp2 <- data.table( theta = psi )
tmp2[,R := 4 * a * cos(theta) * sin(theta) * sin(theta) ]
tmp2$group = 2
polar(tmp2$theta,tmp2$R,typ='l',col='red')
polar(tmp1$theta,tmp1$R,typ='l',col='green',add=TRUE)
tmp <- rbind(tmp1,tmp2)
setkey(tmp,group,theta)

set.seed(1)
noise=6
tmp[,c('xn','yn') := list(R*cos(theta),
                        R*sin(theta))]
tmp$x <- tmp$xn + runif(nrow(tmp),min=-.05,max=+.05)*noise
tmp$y <- tmp$yn + runif(nrow(tmp),min=-.05,max=+.05)*noise
print(ggplot(tmp)+geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y,group=group)) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xn,y=yn,group=group),col='green') )
tmp[,c('dx','dy') := list(c(0,x[2:.N]-x[1:(.N-1)]),
                          c(0,y[2:.N]-y[1:(.N-1)])),by=group]
tmp[,c('speed') := list(sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy))]
tmp[,c('tang_accel') := list(c(0,speed[2:.N]-speed[1:(.N-1)]))]
tmp[,c('speedLimited','tang_accel_limited') := list(pmin(speed,.4),
                                                    pmin(tang_accel,.5))]

print( ggplot(tmp)+geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y,group=group,col=speedLimited,size=tang_accel_limited)) )
print( ggplot(tmp) + 
         geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y,group=group,col=speedLimited,size=tang_accel_limited)) + 
         discrete_scale(scale_name='speedLimited',aes(),palette = colorRamp(c("red", "yellow", "green")) ) )
```

I don't know how to correct the last line to vary the line color palette, or how to specify break value for the line color or line size.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming problem or is your question 'only' about suggestions on how to visualize your data? If the latter, it may become closed as off-topic for SO. Why do you have "How to vary color and width" in the title when you have already solved that problem? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: OK, I updated the question to contain an actual programming question.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the exact same thing.